# How can I install Maven plug-in in Anypoint Studio?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

For one of my POC, I need to get Maven plug-in installed in my Mule Anypoint studio. How I can install the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click Help > Install New Software and in Work with, click Anypoint Addons Update Site > Maven Tools for Mule. Click Next and follow the install prompts:
you can follow the next instructions from the below links.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/using-maven-with-mule

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps provided by Pratikkumar. Please remember either you need to get settings.xml from your client or get authentication details to connect nexus repository and create settings.xml. This settings.xml should be placed under .m2 folder(Local repository).

Answer (score 1):

- maven installed on your local machine contains conf folder under that global (settings.xml) is available.
- copy the settings.xml and placed under .m2 folder(Local repository).
  .m2 folder is generated by executing mvn in cmd prompt.
- place the authentication details in settings.xml to connect with nexus repository(if it enterprise)

Answer (score 1):

In Anypoint studio click on help==>click on install new software and follow the steps provided in the below image url.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGixo.png

After completing this process change the Installed JRE'S in build path to JDK and restart Any point studio.